# Tracking the changes made to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, polling

I have made a simple Key-Value store using a dictionary in python which supports the addition of a KV pair, retrieval of a value for a particular key and get all the KV pairs. I want to add one watch feature as well wherein, it should run infinitely and show me the real-time changes made to my KV store. How to track the changes made to my dictionary? And then is polling a good option to display them in real-time?

Comment: You'll need to create a subclass of `dict()`, and implement your own method for updating the contents that notifies watchers.

Comment: Instead of polling, use callbacks that get called when something changes.

Comment: But how will I display them in real-time without polling or running an infinite loop? A bit confused here. The watch feature should display all the changes to KV store happening in real-time until the user interrupts to terminate the operation.

Comment: The callback function updates the display. You don't need to do anything in a loop, since nothing needs to be done when the value isn't changing.